# Transform a named vector in data frame

Tags: r

I have the following vector:

```
dput(z1)
c(Measure = "Height", IFS = "12,636.00", IFS = "15,401.00", 
IFS = "15,371.00", IFS = "16,218.00", IFS = "20,975.00", Measure = "Height", 
IFS = "12,258.00", IFS = "12,542.00", IFS = "13,014.00", IFS = "13,508.00", 
IFS = "11,934.00", Measure = "Height", IFS = "5,854.46", IFS = "6,500.39", 
IFS = "5,208.78", IFS = "4,221.37", NA, Measure = "Height", 
IFS = "845.70", IFS = "1,161.30", IFS = "1,217.80", IFS = "875.90", 
IFS = "401.90", Measure = "Height", IFS = "34,416.00", IFS = "33,249.00", 
IFS = "32,942.00", IFS = "33,174.00", IFS = "33,267.00", Measure = "Height", 
IFS = "2,390.00", IFS = "2,269.00", IFS = "1,902.00", IFS = "1,710.20", 
IFS = "1,734.60")
```

I would like to transform it into a data frame that would look like this:

```
Measure    IFS          IFS       IFS           IFS          IFS     

Height    12,636.00  15,401.00  15,371.00   16,218.00     20,975.00
Height    12,258.00  12,542.00  13,014.00   13,508.00     11,934.00
Height    5,854.46   6,500.39   5,208.78    4,221.37       NA
```

... plus the three more rows. That is the first 6 values are a row and so on.

I tried

```
z1<-stack(z1) then
z1<-t(z1)
z1<-as.data.frame(z1)
z1<-matrix( z1, ncol=6)
```

But the data is not arranging the way I need it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could `split` into a `list`, based on the presence of 'Height' and collapse them by `rbind`ing with `map_dfr`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
z2 <- z1[complete.cases(z1)]
map_dfr(split(z2, cumsum(z2 %in% 'Height')), as.data.frame.list)
```

-output

```
Measure       IFS     IFS.1     IFS.2     IFS.3     IFS.4
1  Height 12,636.00 15,401.00 15,371.00 16,218.00 20,975.00
2  Height 12,258.00 12,542.00 13,014.00 13,508.00 11,934.00
3  Height  5,854.46  6,500.39  5,208.78  4,221.37      <NA>
4  Height    845.70  1,161.30  1,217.80    875.90    401.90
5  Height 34,416.00 33,249.00 32,942.00 33,174.00 33,267.00
6  Height  2,390.00  2,269.00  1,902.00  1,710.20  1,734.60
```

Comment: Thanks akrun it works as you show. But I am getting only the first three rows. I can't get the next three.

Comment: @Vasile sorry, that is a bug from my side.  It should be `%n%` instead of `==` as there are NA elements in your data, which returns NA with `==` and thus cumsum from that point onwards is NA

Comment: Thanks, works now. One more question. My vector is longer than in the example, so what is [-7] in your code? Do I have to adjust it?  I tried the code on 7 rows and it gives me two additional columns with NA in them. I tried with 8 rows and I get the same two additional columns with NA. If it stays the same over the thousands of rows that I have it is not a problem as I can delete the two columns. But just curious what is -7

Comment: @Vasile.  It is just that there is a NA column at the end, which I removed it.  It is only because of the data you had whic showed some NAs

Comment: Yes, of course. I just tried with the entire dataset (the vector has 9792 values) and I get 7 additional NA columns (6 additional when tried with 120 values). As I said not a problem as I can delete them, but do you know why this is happening? Can I trim it somehow from the code?

Comment: @Vasile in your original data, there is only a single NA i.e. `which(is.na(z1))
   
18`.  May be you could subset first before doing this i.e. `z2 <- z1[complete.cases(z1)]` and then use the code

Comment: This approach adds only 3 NA columns, but still adds them. Anyway, it does not matter for my purpose. Thanks again.

Comment: @Vasile May be there are some elements without any name as well in the original data

Comment: How do I check it? I tried str() but nothing informative.

Comment: @Vasile how big is your data.  If you can `dput`, can check

Comment: the vector has 9792 values, so quite big. Don't worry, akrun. I was just curious.

Comment: @Vasile I am also curious as to why it happened.

Comment: Can you use the dput that I provided in the question? It adds the NA column as well, so if there is something, you should see it there?

Comment: @Vasile it didn't add that column `z2 <- z1[complete.cases(z1)]; map_dfr(split(z2, cumsum(z2 %in% 'Height')), as.data.frame.list)`

Comment: ok, thanks. I meant the initial code which was adding  a column.  I see the latest one does not add when used with smaller number of variables.

Comment: @Vasile yes, that is confusing to me that once we remove those NAs.  Probably, you have some character `"NA"` elements in the original data which is not removed

Comment: z2 <- z1[complete.cases(z1)]
> anyNA(z2)
[1] FALSE

Comment: @Vasile I meant if you have "NA" character it won't show up in `is.na` or `anyNA`

Comment: Yes you're right. I am not very good at R. I tried "NA" %in% z1
[1] FALSE
> NA %in% z1
[1] TRUE

Comment: So you may check `sum(z1 == "NA", na.rm = TRUE)` to get the count of those elements

Comment: sum(z1 == "NA", na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0
> sum(z1 == NA, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0

Comment: @Vasile then, I am not sure what is happening there :=).Would there by leading/lagging spaces ? i.e. usage of `trimws`

Comment: could be. if you're interested I can check just tell me how.

Comment: @Vasile I would just check the `list` before doing the rbind that is `map(split(z2, cumsum(z2 %in% 'Height')), as.data.frame.list)` and then look for the position in the 'z2' vector which returned this NA

Comment: so this gives me the huge output. how do I check for spaces there?

Comment: I would check where those NA columns are present by going through each list element.  It is only 9792 values

Comment: sorry akrun, I do not know how to do this. I saved it using the code you provided in z2. I assume sum would check the entire list. so sum(z2 == "NA", na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 0

Comment: @Vasile that implies you don't have character "NA", but there could other issues which I am not sure without knowing the full data

Comment: well this will remain a mystery, then:)?. Thanks for your help. I remember you from about 5 years ago when I just started with R. I have not been doing anything until this year . so did not advance much . But your answers were very helpful then and now. I

Comment: @Vasile I would say if you dig deeper into this, you will learn more :=). i.e. may notice some bugs (if present etc.)

Comment: I'll be working with this data and if I notice anything, will let you know.